# Running triggers with an admin user or system access

Tags: apex, trigger, security

We have several validations that we run on some of our custom objects in triggers (e.g., after update, after insert, etc.). Many of these validations are one time validations from a system perspective that the user inserting or updating the record does not need to know about. The validations also work with custom fields that should not be visible to the user but we have to make it visible/writeable because the trigger is run from the users perspective.

1- Main Validation: that runs from the users perspective

2- System Validation: that runs from the system/admin perspective and is completely hidden from the user.

[Run Trigger As A Specific User (or Profile)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10317/run-trigger-as-a-specific-user-or-profile) suggests that the validation rule is blocking what the user wants to achieve and the focus of the topic is Validation Rules while we do not use Validation Rules at all and have everything in the triggers.

Using system.runas(admin) obviously does not work in production as it only works with tests.

Another option is using without sharing in the trigger, which will bypass the FLS but cannot be done because as far as I know it will fail the package in security review.

What is the best solution here?

Comment: Updated with some more details. I understand it is the same idea but I think the context and usage is different.

Answer (score 4):

Validations, whether run as a Validation Rule or in before/after triggers occur at the Domain Layer and the 'rule' will execute when a DML event occurs.  This is by design - avoid saving data that will corrupt the database's integrity.

Conditional execution of a validation can thus use only information available to the domain layer:

- The running user (and information about the running user -- profile, role, etc.)
- Custom settings (Only Hierarchical custom settings for VR)
- Custom metadata type (for Apex only)
- Some value(s) in the SObject itself, set by the client app/class that is invoking the DML
- System run dateTime

If you want to run validations that are warnings only (for the admins), you can consider executing them in queueables or future, logging results to a custom object.